# Solaris 10 - Is it possible to reboot a system from a startup script?

Tags: solaris, startup, reboot, runlevel

I have a Solaris 10 test guest logical domain (LDom). I plan to have the network on this be reconfigured before rebooting using a startup script in `/etc/rc0.d`.

At the moment, when the system boots, everything in the startup script is run as I want it to be, except that the reboot does not occur.

I have created a test script, and stripped it of everything except the essentials:

```
#!/sbin/sh

# MAIN

case "$1" in
start)
   if [ -f /etc/DR_Network_Configured ]; then
      exit 0
   else
      touch /etc/DR_Network_Configured
      reboot
   fi
   exit 0
   ;;
*)
   echo "Usage: $0 { start }"
   exit 1
   ;;
esac
exit 0
```

If I run the script from the command line, `/etc/rc0.d/S99testing start`, the file `/etc/DR_Network_Configured` is created and the system immediately reboots, i.e. the desired behaviour.

However, if I remove the file `/etc/DR_Network_Configured`, shut the system down, and boot it again, the file `/etc/DR_Network_Configured` gets recreated by the script during boot, but no subsequent reboot occurs.

Is there a fail-safe mechanism to stop startup scripts from potentially causing infinite reboots? If so, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested moving this script from `/etc/rc0.d` to `/etc/rcS.d`, `/etc/rc1.d`, `/etc/rc2.d` and `/etc/rc3.d` with the following results:

- **/etc/rcS.d** - same behaviour as `/etc/rc0.d` - /etc/DR_Network_Configured is created, but no reboot occurs.
- **/etc/rc1.d** - /etc/DR_Network_Configured is not created, and no reboot happens.
- **/etc/rc2.d** - /etc/DR_Network_Configured is created and the system is rebooted.
- **/etc/rc3.d** - /etc/DR_Network_Configured is created and the system is rebooted.

To summarise, when the system is booted to its default (`milestone/multi-user-server:default`, similar to run-level 3), it executes startup scripts located in `/etc/rc0.d`, `/etc/rcS.d`, `/etc/rc2.d` and `/etc/rc3.d`, but not `/etc/rc1.d`.

The reboot and init commands do not work when run from a startup script in `/etc/rc0.d`, `/etc/rcS.d` (and possibly `/etc/rc1.d` although I can't confirm this as the startup script in this directory never ran). They do work when run from startup scripts in `/etc/rc2.d` and `/etc/rc3.d`.

I imagine that this is designed to prevent a system from constantly rebooting. Should an erroneous startup script in `/etc/rc2.d` or `/etc/rc3.d` put the system into an infinite reboot loop, then the system can be fairly easily be rebooted to the single-user milestone and the offending startup script disabled rather than having to locate alternate boot media to boot off, mount the root volume/disk and disable the offending script.

Based on the above, I have modified my network reconfiguration script as follows:

1. Kept my script in `/etc/rc0.d` to change the network settings.
2. Added a function to it so that if the system needs to be rebooted after reconfiguring the network, a new script `/etc/rc2.d/S99reboot` is created which will reboot the system.
3. If the `/etc/DR_Network_Configured` file exists, and `/etc/rc2.d/S99reboot` exists, then remove the latter to avoid the system constantly rebooting.

My relevant code is:

```
#!/sbin/sh
reboot_script="/etc/rc2.d/S99reboot"

Create_Reboot_File ()
{
   echo "#!/sbin/sh" > $reboot_script
   echo "case \"\$1\" in" >> $reboot_script
   echo "start)" >> $reboot_script
   echo "  init 6" >> $reboot_script
   echo "  exit 0" >> $reboot_script
   echo "  ;;" >> $reboot_script
   echo "esac" >> $reboot_script
   echo "exit 0" >> $reboot_script
   chmod 740 $reboot_script
   chown root:root $reboot_file
}

case "$1" in
start)
   if [ -f /etc/DR_Network_Configured ]; then
      [ -f $reboot_script ] && rm $reboot_script
      exit 0
   else
      # My reconfigure network functions are here
      # ...
      touch /etc/DR_Network_Configured
      Create_Reboot_File
   fi
   exit 0
   ;;
*)
   echo "Usage: $0 { start }"
   exit 1
   ;;
esac
exit 0
```